# Omit a Value in a Multiple-Assignment Ternary Conditional

Tags: python, python-3.x, conditional-statements, variable-assignment

**Scenario:**

Quicksort coding challenge.

Input is two lines: Line 1 = Pivot, Line 2 is an unsorted list of integers
Output is a list, with the values less than the pivot shifted to the left, followed by the pivot and the values >= to the pivot.

**Example:**

Input:

```
7
1 2 4 9 3 7 11 5 12
```

Output:

```
1 2 4 3 5 7 9 11 12
```

**What I would like to do in Python 3 (if possible):**

left,right = [ *(value,DO NOT ASSIGN)* for value in unsortedList if value < pivot else *(DO NOT ASSIGN, value)* ]

**Question:**

Is there a way to do what I'm trying to do? I understand how to assign the values individually, but was curious if in multiple-assignments you are required to assign a value.

'None' will not work as its a list and I need to maintain the previous values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I mean, you could do something like this, which sort of approximates the same effect by means of `filter`. Note that the `list(filter(...))` thing is just to materialize the filters so they print correctly.

```
>>> unsorted = [1, 2, 4, 9, 3, 7, 11, 5, 12]
>>> pivot = 7
>>> left, right = [list(filter(lambda n: n < pivot, unsorted)), list(filter(lambda n: n >= pivot, unsorted))]
>>> left
[1, 2, 4, 3, 5]
>>> right
[9, 7, 11, 12]
```

But there is no "DO NOT ASSIGN" syntactic primitive in Python.

Answer (score 0):

You can sort of fake it with `None`, `zip` and a `filter` at the end (though you'd also have to reposition the 7 for quicksort):

```
In [1]: l = map(int, "1 2 4 9 3 7 11 5 12".split())

In [2]: left, right = zip(*[(v, None) if v < 7 else (None, v) for v in l])

In [3]: left, right
Out[3]:
((1, 2, 4, None, 3, None, None, 5, None),
 (None, None, None, 9, None, 7, 11, None, 12))

In [4]: filter(lambda x: x is not None, left), filter(lambda x: x is not None, right)
Out[4]: ((1, 2, 4, 3, 5), (9, 7, 11, 12))
```

Comment: Note that `filter(None, iterable)` will remove falsy values (including `0`) from `iterable`, which would probably be bad for a sort algorithm.